# Why is my middleware leaking memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, memory-leaks, rack

I've forked the [rack-timeout gem](https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout) so I could add some features -- namely, catching the incidents of timeouts, logging them, and sending a 503.

[Here's my fork](https://github.com/ganxy/rack-timeout).

[Here's the Rack app/middleware in my fork](https://github.com/ganxy/rack-timeout/blob/master/lib/rack/timeout.rb#L1).

The behavior is as expected. However, since deploying, my app's memory footprint grows and grows steadily until I have to restart it. While it's growing, its behavior is correct and its performance is seemingly normal.

When I first noticed this, I thought it might be because in the cases where a request did die out, some threads/memory were kept hanging around. This line of experimentation resulted in [this patch](https://github.com/ganxy/rack-timeout/commit/a2fec98440d183c7b1a1040d51fd541a74632896). Indeed, in my local tests, without this patch memory grows steadily when the app is hit with (intentionally) timing out requests, and with the patch the memory stays low and normal.

So, I thought I fixed the problem. But I did not -- the memory on my production app still grows continuously. (I haven't tried testing my app locally in production mode -- I'll do that next).

What could be causing the memory leak in my Rack app?

Comment: Why the extra thread - why not `::Timeout.timeout(self.class.time, Rack::Timeout::AppTimeout) {@app.call(env)}`. Definitely worth testing in production mode - code reloading can mask memory leaks

Comment: because without that wrapper thread, when Timeout raises its exception, the exception is handled by middleware down the stack instead of in mine. this is because of the implementation of Tomeout.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lambda in your Timeout class, which is a closure. Since there is no need for it, I would just define a method instead. Not sure if this is the cause, but it is definitely a probable cause for memory leaks.